# Is there a limit to the number of partition columns of DolphinDB?

Tags: database, partition, data-partitioning, dolphindb

does DolphinDB have a limit on the number of partition columns that can be specified?

Suppose most of the columns of a table have the same value range(100 columns), can I create the partition table by specifying all of them?

Answer (score 0):

A DolphinDB table has up to three partitioning columns